# Google Tag Manager crashes IE9

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website that uses GTM. It works fine on Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE11. On IE9 the browser crashes. Has anyone experienced this? How can I debug it? Since the browser is crashing I have nothing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of tags do you use? Maybe the problem is in some tag.